# How to deal with inconsistent PHP warnings (especially in context of local hosting vs online hosting)?

Tags: localhost, web-hosting

I know my code is shabby, but I don't think it's really that at fault for it here?

Managed to work out how to redirect users to different pages depending on their level as given through a login/register form, and it worked okay locally on my computer. No errors or bugs detected, and by manual testing it seemed okay.

I then uploaded the entire login/register program on a free hosting site (000webhost) with essentially identical code, yet the outcomes are very different for my validation process: [post-login screen, locally hosted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye2uL.png); [post-login screen, on 000webhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTomK.png).

Specifically, the errors are:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "level" in /storage/ssd1/382/21909382/public_html/validation.php on line 15

Warning: Undefined array key "admin" in /storage/ssd1/382/21909382/public_html/validation.php on line 27

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd1/382/21909382/public_html/validation.php:15) in /storage/ssd1/382/21909382/public_html/validation.php on line 28
```

The lines in question are:

```
Line 15: $level = $_POST['level'];

Line 27: $_SESSION["admin"];

Line 28: header('location:Admin Page.php');
```

Here is the complete file where the errors appear:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','id21909382_biyo','!Biyo123');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'id21909382_access_levels');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$level = $_POST['level'];

echo $value ?? '';

$select = " select * from usertable where name = '$name' && password = '$pass'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $select);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row['level'] == 'admin'){
        $_SESSION["admin"];
        header('location:Admin Page.php');

    }elseif($row['level'] == 'user'){
        $_SESSION["user"];
        header('location:User Page.php');
        
    }

}else{
    header('location:index.php');
}

}

?>
```

It's already strange enough that the two have vastly different outcomes despite being the same (the only thing that varies between them is $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','id21909382_biyo','!Biyo123');) due to 000webhost having different credentials for phpmyadmin. Even worse, all of the error-lines have similar ones that are error-free: line 27's $_SESSION["admin"]; is similar to $_SESSION["user"]; just a few lines after, for example. Much of the code is also copy-pasted from the registration file within my program, yet no problems there.

What exactly did I do wrong that is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: This is all down to your code not checking whether the `$_POST` variables exist before you use them. Note that the line `$_SESSION["admin"];` doesn't actually do anything, but will complain if the element in `$_SESSION` doesn't exist. The message 'Headers already sent' arises becaues PHP has already emitted the warnings.

Answer (score -1):

The problem eventually resolved itself. Randomly tried logging in again and it spontaneously worked.

Comment: The problem hasn't resolved itself. You've just hit on some conditions that, by luck, happen to work without showing errors. Your code is haphazard and has non-functional lines that will generate warnings without benefit. If you don't take time to understand why your code failed it will fail again, in this project or the next, and you'll be as clueless as before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).